# Double backslash in comment inside array

Tags: c++, arrays, comments

I have an array defined as follows:

```
extern const char config_reg[] = {  
  0x05, //comment
  0x00, //comment
  0x00, //  \\    <-- double backslash
  0x01, //comment
  0x03
}
```

As you can see, there is a double backslash inside a comment (the `<-- double backslash` and preceding spaces do not appear in the actual source file). When I compile this code (minus the "<-- double backslash") it acts as if the **following** line is non existent - i.e. equivalent to writing:

```
extern const char config_reg[] = {  
  0x05, //comment
  0x00, //comment
  0x00, //  

  0x03
}
```

Is this intended C++ behaviour? If so, what is its intended purpose?

I am compiling using the Parallax Propeller Simple IDE to compile my code - not a particularly good compiler, by all accounts. Is it likely that the compiler implementation is causing this behaviour?

Comment: Just to make things worse, a `\` is supposed to be treated as a line continuation character only at the very end of a line. If the line ended with `\\ ` (two backslashes and a space), then in principle the line wouldn't be spliced. At least that's my interpretation; the authors of gcc (or of the Gnu preprocessor) appear not to agree.

Comment: @KeithThompson: see the quote I gave from the standard.  If the last character is a backslash, independent of what goes before that backslash, the line is concatenated.  Hence my comment that two backslashes are not necessary; one is sufficient to get the comment concatenation behaviour.  You can have some fun with backslash-newline between the slash and star of a `/* comment */` or between the two slashes of a `// comment`.  Or, indeed, several backslash-newline sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the second phase of translation involves "splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines"; if a line ends with a backslash, the following line is considered to be a continuation of that line. This is the standard behaviour. This occurs **before** the removal of comments in the third phase, so the fact that the backslash occurs in a comment doesn't change anything.

Line splicing is used quite frequently in C to split macros over multiple lines, since a preprocessor directive extends to the end of the line. It is much rarer in C++, which relies much less on macros than C.

I believe the original purpose in C was to work around restrictions on line length that existed on some now-archaic systems.

Comment: It's not just about restrictions on line lengths. It means very long macro definitions can be written on multiple lines, which can make them much more legible.

Answer (score 2):

That's correct, assuming that the `<-- double backslash` and preceding spaces aren't actually in the code.

A single backslash would also produce the same effect.

The newline splicing for backslash-newline occurs before comment analysis, so the `0x01` line is part of the same line as the `// \\` comment, so it isn't seen when the comment analysis is done.

The ISO/IEC 14882:2011 (C++11) standard says:

> #### 2.2 Phases of translation [lex.phases]
>
> ¶1 The precedence among the syntax rules of translation is specified by the following phases.<sup>11</sup>
>
> 1. Physical source file characters are mapped, in an implementation-defined manner, to the basic source
>      character set (introducing new-line characters for end-of-line indicators) if necessary. The set of physical
>      source file characters accepted is implementation-defined. Trigraph sequences (2.4) are replaced
>      by corresponding single-character internal representations. Any source file character not in the basic
>      source character set (2.3) is replaced by the universal-character-name that designates that character.
>      (An implementation may use any internal encoding, so long as an actual extended character
>      encountered in the source file, and the same extended character expressed in the source file as a
>      universal-character-name (i.e., using the `\uXXXX` notation), are handled equivalently except where this
>      replacement is reverted in a raw string literal.)
> 2. Each instance of a backslash character (`\`) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted,
>      splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical
>      source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. If, as a result, a character sequence that
>      matches the syntax of a universal-character-name is produced, the behavior is undefined. A source file
>      that is not empty and that does not end in a new-line character, or that ends in a new-line character
>      immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place, shall be processed
>      as if an additional new-line character were appended to the file.
> 3. The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens (2.5) and sequences of white-space characters
>      (including comments). A source file shall not end in a partial preprocessing token or in a partial comment.<sup>12</sup> Each comment is replaced by one space character. New-line characters are retained. Whether
>      each nonempty sequence of white-space characters other than new-line is retained or replaced by one
>      space character is unspecified. The process of dividing a source file’s characters into preprocessing tokens
>      is context-dependent. [ *Example:* see the handling of `<` within a `#include` preprocessing directive.
>      —*end example* ]
>
> <sup>11)</sup> Implementations must behave as if these separate phases occur, although in practice different phases might be folded
>   together.
>
> <sup>12)</sup> A partial preprocessing token would arise from a source file ending in the first portion of a multi-character token that
>   requires a terminating sequence of characters, such as a header-name that is missing the closing `"` or `>`. A partial comment
>   would arise from a source file ending with an unclosed `/*` comment.

Answer (score 1):

A `\` at the end of a line escapes the newline character.

Thus in your example, it will extend the comment to the next line. The writer of the snippet probably used `\\` instead of just `\` for aesthetic purposes. But it doesn't only work with comments. For example this is allowed (but redundant):

```
int a; \
int b;
```

Some compilers allow whitespace between the `\` and the newline but may issue a warning.